# What is the right way to pass nested objects in object array in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, react-props, array.prototype.map

In my map function below I am trying to access the nested objects in my data. I would like to say that "If an object in my SlideData has the property "list", display it". I am passing props from the data to my TextSlide component, but there must be a better way than passing a ton of props to the TextComponent?

```
function Slideshow(props) {

//MY DATA
const SlideData = [{
{
    title: "The Title",
    text1: "Monkey",
    text2: "D",
    text3: "Luffy",
    list: [
            {
              listTitle: "The List",
              listItem1: "Zoro",
              listItem2: "Nami",
              listItem3: "Sanji",
              listItem4: "Ussop",
              listItem5: "Chopper",
              listItem6: "Franky",
            },
          ],
    imagesrc: picture,
    imagewidth: "100px",
  },
}]
```

```
//MAP THROUGH DATA (is there a better way to pass multiple props here?? maybe with {...props} ?)

const textSlides = SlideData.map((item),index) => ( <TextSlide
      key={index}
      title={item.title}
      text1={item.text1}
      text2={item.text2}
      listTitle={item.listTitle}
      listItem1={item.listItem1}
      listItem2={item.listItem2}
      listItem3={item.listItem3}
      listItem4={item.listItem4}
      listItem5={item.listItem5}
      listItem6={item.listItem6}
  />));

return (
    <>
        {textSlides}
    </>
  );
}
```

//TEXTSLIDE COMPONENT//

```
const TextSlide = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="slide">
        <div className="standard-grid">
          <span className="slide-title title">{props.title}</span>
             <div className="content">
               <p>{props.text1}</p>      
               <p>{props.text2}</p>         
               <p>{props.text3}</p>       
               {props.list ? <div>
                <h4>{props.list2}</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li>{props.listItem1}</li>
                  <li>{props.listItem2}</li>
                  <li>{props.listItem3}</li>
                  <li>{props.listItem4}</li>
                  <li>{props.listItem5}</li>
                  <li>{props.listItem6}</li>
                </ul>
              </div> : null} 
             </div>
            {props.imagesrc ? (<img className="picture" src={props.imagesrc} 
            style={{ maxWidth: props.imagewidth }} alt="image" />) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TextSlide;
```

Comment: Is there always a static number (i.e. 6) list item values? Is `list` always an array of length 1 with the list items as properties in a single object? I would suggest first massaging your slide data into a structure/shape that lends itself to being more easily rendered. Where does the current `SlideData` array/object structure come from? Do you have control over the source?

Comment: The data might include multiple objects each with varying amounts of text, listTitle, list items, or text properties. But the data will be located locally in a js file and imported into the slideshow component. So my goal is to make various slides, with a textcomponent that is rendered based on this data. So one slide might have 8 list items and the next might have 3 etc. does that help?

Comment: I believe so. So it sounds like you've some control over the data format, is this correct?

Comment: correct, each slide will show different information based on the objects in the slidedata file. so if I want to add a slide I just go that slideData file and create a new object in the array. Its kind of like a power point slide show where each slide usually has a similar layout but different data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems like you've a bit of control over the data structure and format, I would suggest trying to format your data in such a way that lends itself to being easily renderable. In React, lists are commonly converted/stored in arrays so that they can be mapped to JSX.

Example:

```
const SlideData = [
  {
    title: "The Title",
    text: ["Monkey", "D","Luffy", ...];
    list: {
      title: "The List",
      items: [ "Zoro", "Nami", "Sanji", "Ussop", "Chopper", "Franky"],
    },
    image: {
      src: picture,
      width: "100px",
    },
  },
  ...
];
```

Anywhere you were previously using essentially a duplicate "itemX" key is a prime candidate to be stored as an array.

You can simply pass an entire object property as a prop, and render and pass on any nested properties.

Example:

```
const textSlides = SlideData.map((item, index) => (
  <TextSlide
    key={index}
    {...item}
  />
));
```

Child

```
const TextSlide = ({
  title,
  text = [],
  list,
  image,
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="slide">
      <div className="standard-grid">
        <span className="slide-title title">{title}</span>
        <div className="content">
          {text.map((t, i) => <p key={i}>{t}</p>)}
          {list && (
            <div>
              <h4>{list.title}</h4>
              <ul>
                {list.items.map((item, i) => (
                  <li key={i}>{item}</li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        {image && (
          <img
            className="picture"
            src={image.src} 
            style={{ maxWidth: image.width }}
            alt="image"
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is the way I was wanting, I  just didnt know how! thanks you

Answer (score 4):

You should prefer to use `<TextSlide {...props} />` instead of pass many props, it's more readable.

```
    SlideData.map((slide) => (
    <TextSlide key={slide.id} {...slide} />
  ))
```

- Quick tip: Don't use index as key, you can read more information about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

I also recommended to you to do a little refactor to your code:

Store your listData in relevant object instead of array

```
 {
  id: 1,
  title: "The Title",
  text1: "Monkey",
  text2: "D",
  text3: "Luffy",
  listData: {
    listTitle: "The List",
    listItem1: "Zoro",
    listItem2: "Nami",
    listItem3: "Sanji",
    listItem4: "Ussop",
    listItem5: "Chopper",
    listItem6: "Franky"
  },
  imagesrc: "picture",
  imagewidth: "100px"
}
```

After this change you can work more easily with your data, let's take a look at your example with some changes:

TextSlide Component

```
  const TextSlide = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="slide">
        <div className="standard-grid">
          <span className="slide-title title">{props.title}</span>
          <div className="content">
            <p>{props.text1}</p>
            <p>{props.text2}</p>
            <p>{props.text3}</p>
            {props.listData ? (
              <div>
                <h4>{listData.list2}</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li>{listData.listItem1}</li>
                  <li>{listData.listItem2}</li>
                  <li>{listData.listItem3}</li>
                  <li>{listData.listItem4}</li>
                  <li>{listData.listItem5}</li>
                  <li>{listData.listItem6}</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          {props.imagesrc ? (
            <img
              className="picture"
              src={props.imagesrc}
              style={{ maxWidth: props.imagewidth }}
              alt="image"
            />
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TextSlide;
```

Comment: This is nice, and yes I  will do. I am curious though, if I had another object, with let’s say 20 list items, then do I have to write 20 <li>{list data.listitem#}</li> Tags in the TextComponent return statement? Or do you normally loop/map through that as well?

Comment: In this case i would prefer to create another component to render all the list items and pass the listData of each slide.

Comment: makes sense! I def want the cleanest way to write it